# NamedVirtiaulHosts not working despite correct configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

Ubuntu 14.04 server, Apache2. I have  a Prestashop webshop under domain.tld, which is working fine.
I now want to install webmail on my service, so I have added a virtual host that points to /var/www/webmail.

However, when I go to webmail.domain.tld, I always get redirect to domain.tld.

I've Google a lot and it all looks good. This is the output of  DUMP_VHOSTS

```
root@ubuntu-1404:/etc/apache2# apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.domain.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.tld.conf:1)
         port 443 namevhost www.domain.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.tld.conf:1)
                 alias www.domain.tld
                 alias domain.tld
         port 443 namevhost webmail.domain.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webmail.domain.tld.conf:1)
                 alias webmail.domain.tld
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.domain.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.tld.conf:48)
         port 80 namevhost www.domain.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.tld.conf:48)
                 alias www.domain.tld
                 alias domain.tld
         port 80 namevhost webmail.domain.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webmail.domain.tld.conf:39)
                 alias webmail.domain.tld
```

I also added webmail.domain.tld to my hosts-file (127.0.0.1) and when I test using telnet 80, it does not work either.

I found a lot of posts saying that I have to add NamedVirtualHost:80, but that seems deprecated, as I then get an error that this command no longer works.
I've also checked httpd.conf for REWRITES, but cannot find one. I've also tried to remove "domain.tld" as an alias of the default site, but that does not make a difference either.

The relevant configuration (in 2 .conf files):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld domain.tld
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.tld/public_html
    # ....
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld domain.tld
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.tld/public_html
    # ....
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName webmail.domain.tld
    ServerAlias webmail.domain.tld

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webmail
    # ....  
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName webmail.domain.tld
    ServerAlias webmail.domain.tld

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webmail
    # ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Please shed a light on this.

Comment: So, what does the actual configuration look like?

Comment: Updated my post, added the relevant configuration.

Comment: Don't know why this receives a -1 without a comment, very useful. 

But I've solved it... Dang. It works in a FireFox in private window... So it was a matter of caching :@

Comment: If you've got an answer to your own question, you're encouraged to post and accept it below, so that others might find and benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out to be caching. FireFox was caching the redirect, when I tested in an InPrivate Chrome/Firefox it was working as expected.